# Laravel Queue Breaks On Live Server Works Well on Local

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I need help with my Laravel App, the queue breaks (gives funny errors) on Digital Ocean server, but works perfectly well and fast on my local. The error on the server often changes from eloquent error to undefined variable.
The error says "General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value..." 
[here's an image of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZd61.png)

However the value gets inputed just fine on my local.

Here's the code

```
public function saveEmailsIntoDb($id)
{
    $list = EmailList::where('job_id',$id)->first();
   $contents = file(public_path('files/'.$list->stored_file_name), FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
   foreach ($contents as $value) 
   {
        Email::create([
            'user_id'       => $list->user_id,
            'email_list_id' => $list->id,
            'email'         => $value
        ]);
    }

    $credits = count($contents);
    User::where('id',$list->user_id)->decrement('credits', $credits);
    unlink(public_path('files/'.$list->stored_file_name));
    EmailList::where('stored_file_name',$list->stored_file_name)
             ->update(['is_deleted' => 1]);
    return $list->id;
}
```

I run apache on my local, i have nginx configured on Digital Ocean.

The code works once in a while (randomly), but give this error on most times. The queue driver is database.

Comment: The actual errors would be handy in order to get help :) 

Also, is the config, especially queue driver the same?

Comment: please post the error, the type of server you're using (apache/nginx); also check the .env file, the server config and the server access and error log. did you do php artisan config:clear when you uploaded the project?

Comment: have  you restarted ur queue after the deplo, please? if not u should do that with php artisan queue:restart

Comment: @matiit i have updated the question

Comment: @Indra Please see the updated question

Comment: Check the database on the server and see if the column has the same properties. If you don't have access though phpmyadmin or other system you can do that from the mysql command line with DESC emails.